# How to split multiple mails into users and domains in data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, grok

I have a data in that data we have different emails and i need to have a grok patteren where the emails in the data have to be splitted into users and domains

```
 "2019-07-26T16:04:56.760Z,10.155.61.162,citymail4exedge,10.141.6.34,CSMAIL-DR.NYC.GOV,08D70FED2805DAAC;250 2.6.0 <f732fb6f-25ce-46dc-a56e-0f02d1c2dcb3@citymail4exedge.nycnet> [InternalId=54732279] Queued mail for delivery,to CS,SMTP,SEND,446859,<f732fb6f-25ce-46dc-a56e-0f02d1c2dcb3@citymail4exedge.nycnet>,phonebook@acs.nyc.gov;vincent.fox@acs.nyc.gov,250 2.1.5 Recipient OK;250 2.1.5 Recipient OK,2697,2,,;,ACS Telephone Directory Personal Information Update Request,phonebook@acs.nyc.gov,phonebook@acs.nyc.gov,2019-07-26T16:04:56.119Z;SRV=citymail4exedge.nycnet:TOTAL=0,Originating,,,,"
```

`(?<emailuser>[\w.]+)\@(?<domain>\w+\.\w+\.\w+)(\.\w+)?`

I have tried with that in grok pattern but it's working for single email but want output for multiple mails present in it.

Comment: please add expected result

Answer (score 0):

Add the global flag `/g` to your regex and try to include a pattern for this type of email

```
f732fb6f-25ce-46dc-a56e-0f02d1c2dcb3@citymail4exedge.nycnet
```